# How to convert different numbers per words in different columns (unix)

Tags: unix, awk

I have a big file with 28 columns with 3 different codes (0/0, 1/1 and 0/1) that I want to convert to words. This file has millions of lines, each one beggining with "Chr"

```
Chr10_102 T G 999 DP 38 DP4 37 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0 
Chr1_111 C T 999 DP 37 DP4 37 0/1 1/1 0/0 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/1 1/1 1/1 0/1 0/1 0/0 1/1 0/0 0/0 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/1 1/1 0/1 ...
```

I want to convert the codes in each of the 28 columns and all lines as follow:

`0/0` to `no_variant`
 
`1/1` to `homo`
`0/1` to `het`

How to do that? I converted before it, but I had only one column with 2 codes (0/1 and 1/1) and now I have 28 columns to convert and 3 codes, I used

```
awk '{if ($9=="0/1") {print $0,"het"} else{print $0}}' | awk '{if ($9=="1/1") {print $0,"hom"} else{print $0}}'
```

thanks very much

Clarissa

Comment: Do you need to convert all `0/0` to `no_variant` etc.or just some column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's|0/0|no_variant|g; s|1/1|homo|g; s|0/1|het|g' file
```

As awk, that would be

```
awk '{gsub("0/0","no_variant"); gsub("1/1","homo"); gsub("0/1","het")} 1' file
```

If you need to go column-by-column for some reason, use a for-loop:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {c["0/0"] = "no_variant"; c["0/1"] = "het"; c["1/1"] = "homo"} 
    {for (n=9; n<=NF; n++) {$n = c[$n]}; print}
' file
```